# Deleted Route53 Hosted zone then recreated. Doesn't work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I can't really figure this out and have scoured all through Amazon's documentation looking for anything and still can't get it. I'm hoping someone has dealt with this before.

So I was trying to get a Route53 domain to forward to an S3 bucket. The default 'Hosted Zone' that Route53 makes after registering a domain didn't seem to get the Alias of my S3 bucket, and the Amazon instructions said to make a new Hosted zone. So I deleted the Hosted Zone made by default and made a new one, which it then could get the alias to my S3 bucket and I set it up to forward to my S3 bucket.

But now, the domain just doesn't flat out work at all. In anyway. It has the 'NS' and 'SOA' type record sets in it that get made by default, it looks all similar to my other domains that are working. But it doesn't work. Even making a CNAME forward to google.com does not work. I have waited 24 hours to see if it's DNS needing to update. And no luck.

Did I do something really stupid when I deleted the old hosted zone and made a new one? Do I need to do more manual configuration on the new hosted zone to get it to resolve?

Comment: By default, every route 53 hosted zone has unique name servers assigned.  Have you update your registrar to match the new name servers assigned to your new zone?

Comment: I checked and the 'NameServers' under Registered Domains were not the same in the Hosted Zone I created. So I copy/pasted the NameServers under Registered Domains into the NameServers section in the Hosted zone. However, how do I figure out what should be put in the SOA field? I put the first name server url and left the rest of it in tact. I've left that set up for 24 hours now sitting, but it still doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 13):

You should use your hosted zone's name servers as a domain's name servers, not the other way around.

That is, you should do the following:

1. Find your hosted zone in the list. Click on it (don't go inside)
2. Locate name servers in the right-side panel and record it.
3. Navigate to your domain's details page and change the domain's name servers to match the hosted zone's.
4. Verify that operation completes successfully in the alerts table on the dashboard.
5. Wait until the change propagates.

And revert the charges you've did to hosted zone's name servers (or better delete this zone and create a fresh one)